# Regular expression that remove second occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that removes any second occurrence of a character using the regular expression. Here is my function

```
var removeSecondOccurrence = function(string) {
return string.replace(/(.*)\1/gi, '');
}
```

It's only removing consecutive occurrence. I'd like it to remove even non consecutive one. for example papirana should become pairn.

Please help

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a regex. Iterate over the characters in the string, adding to a new string if it doesn't already contain the char.

Comment: With Michelle's suggestion, an option like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bczYR/) seems to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-regexp solution:

```
 "papirana".split("").filter(function(x, n, self) { return self.indexOf(x) == n }).join("")
```

Regexp code is complicated, because JS doesn't support lookbehinds:

```
str = "papirana";
re = /(.)(.*?)\1/;
while(str.match(re)) str = str.replace(re, "$1$2")
```

or a variation of the first method:

```
"papirana".replace(/./g, function(a, n, str) { return str.indexOf(a) == n ? a : "" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a zero-width lookahead assertion you can do something similar

```
"papirana".replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "")
```

returns

```
"pirna"
```

The letters are of course the same, just in a different order.

Passing the reverse of the string and using the reverse of the result you can get what you're asking for.

Comment: That's brilliant! I wonder if you could achieve the same concept with look-behinds instead (in a manner that preserves the occurrence-order like this does: `"papirana".split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "").split("").reverse().join("");`, which outputs 'pairn' instead of 'pirna').

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with a loop:

```
var removeSecondOccurrence = function(string) {
    var results = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
        if (!results.contains(string.charAt(i)))
            results += string.charAt(i);
}
```

Basically: for each character in the input, if you haven't seen that character already, add it to the results. Clear and readable, at least.

Answer (score 0):

What Michelle said.

In fact, I strongly suspect it cannot be done using regular expressions. Or rather, you can if you reverse the string, remove all but the first occurences, then reverse again, but it's a dirty trick and what Michelle suggests is way better (and probably faster).

If you're still hot on regular expressions...

```
"papirana".
    split("").
    reverse().
    join("").
    replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, '').
    split("").
    reverse().
    join("")

// => "pairn"
```

The reason why you can't find all but the first occurence without all the flippage is twofold:

- JavaScript does not have lookbehinds, only lookaheads
- Even if it did, I don't think any regexp flavour allows variable-length lookbehinds